# Simple Multi-Timer Full-featured Windows Desktop Application

Tags: windows, time-management

I'm looking for a timer Windows application that's simple and full featured. I'm looking for an application that's somehow similar to [Stopwatch & Timer (for Android)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sportstracklive.stopwatch&hl=en) in its functionality.

The basic features that I need them available in the software are:

1. Ability to preview multiple countdown timers or stopwatches in one window. [like this](https://lh3.ggpht.com/AYIZ9-PahE_yD9FqUPHvrY12Js4Ntit1TtfuyvR_PsSfkK38gK6enLzQ3Vw0xFO9qla_=h900-rw)
2. Ability to group countdown timers/stopwatches
3. Ability to distinguish timers/stopwatches (either by naming, styling, and coloring.)
4. Ability to show simple analog animation to give quick feeling for the remaining time. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Oe8.png)
5. Glorious and artistic user interface that doesn't make the user feel nervous or old fashioned.

The best one that I've looked for till now is Windows Timer, but unfortunately it's not a desktop application (It's a windows store application) and it neither has the ability to show timers in a simple small list, nor has the ability to group or nest timers.

Answer (score 4):

[WatchMe](http://www.flamebrain.com/download-watchme/) is nice if you want to have multiple timers in a single window.

As you can see from the screenshot you can view multiple countdown timers or stopwatches in one window, and group timers/stopwatches into tabs. Timers can also be named.

The user interface is very simple too so it shouldn't make you feel too nervous.

[image]

Comment: I like that it has the ability to preview multiple timers in one window. Also, it's able to group timers into tabs. Also, I'm able to distinguish timers via naming,flagging, or adding notes. However, I think, it would be better if there was the ability to style and color timers (fonts and backgrounds). Also the names need to be on the timer not that far. Unfortunately, the user interface looks not very artistic and old fashioned somehow. Also, it would be nicer if there was a simple analog animation to give a quick feeling for time. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Windows apps aren't really about being artistic. That's Mac's territory. Windows apps are more about functionality.

Comment: I mean by artistic: looks nice, simple and well nested beside the full-functionality. There are a lot of Windows apps that are artistic already

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what this program can do that the OP requested? Ideally answers contain so much information that a reader can vet them without ever having to visit a link. The things in omareg's first comment would make a great starting point.

Comment: No problem. The OP got stuck on the artistic qualities though.

Answer (score 1):

XNote Stopwatch is pretty amazing and seems to do most of that

http://www.xnotestopwatch.com

Comment: I like the Excel integration feature in it, but unfortunately it lacks simplicity and is not full featured to save me a lot of time wasted in managing my timers. Thanks for suggestion at all!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what this program can do that the OP requested? Ideally answers contain so much information that a reader can vet them without ever having to visit a link. Also, for graphical programs (especially when looks are requested like in this question) a screen shot would be great.